# Get list of columns where all records have null values in a table - SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that contains millions of records and 50 odd columns, many of these columns have null values for all the records in the table. How do I write a SQL Query that tells me which columns have all null records?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: iirc postgresql allows `select * from TABLENAME where (TABLENAME is null);` to return rows where all columns are null (and conversely `not (TABLENAME is null)`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [bool_and](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE):

```
WITH sample (column1, column2, column3) AS (
    VALUES 
        ('LOREM IPSUM', 'LOREM IPSUM', NULL),
        ('LOREM IPSUM', 'LOREM IPSUM', NULL),
        ('LOREM IPSUM', 'LOREM IPSUM', NULL),
        ('LOREM IPSUM', 'LOREM IPSUM', NULL),
        ('LOREM IPSUM', NULL, NULL)
)
SELECT
    bool_and(column1 IS NULL) AS is_column1_entire_null, 
    bool_and(column2 IS NULL) AS is_column2_entire_null,
    bool_and(column3 IS NULL) AS is_column3_entire_null 
FROM 
    sample
```

A quote from the docs:

> (...) true if all input values are true, otherwise false

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which columns have ALL null values meaning no row has a value a count of that row will be 0 so just check for that.

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when count(col1) = 0 then 'col1' end),
                 (case when count(col2) = 0 then 'col2' end),
                 (case when count(col3) = 0 then 'col3' end),
                 . . .
                ) as columns_with_all_null_values
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach would be something like:

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when count(*) <> count(col1) then 'col1' end),
                 (case when count(*) <> count(col2) then 'col2' end),
                 (case when count(*) <> count(col3) then 'col3' end),
                 . . .
                ) as columns_with_null_values
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
To check all columns have null values :


declare @tablename sysname='test'
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @overall_count int;
SELECT @overall_count = COUNT(1) FROM your_table WHERE  your where condition;

    DECLARE @column sysname;
    DECLARE columns_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT c.name
        FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
        WHERE t.name = @tablename AND c.is_nullable = 1 ;
    OPEN columns_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cursor INTO @column;
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @query = N'
        DECLARE @c int
        SELECT @c = COUNT(1) FROM ' + @tablename + ' your where condition and ' + @column + N' is NULL 
        IF (@c = ' + cast(@overall_count as nvarchar(100))+ ')
            select ''' + @column + N''';'
        print(@query);
        execute sp_executesql @query

        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cursor INTO @column;
    END
    CLOSE columns_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE columns_cursor;
```

Comment: I don't think SQL Server code is appropriate for a question tagged "postgresql". Have you taken the [tour]? Have you visited the [help]?